# sendKeys doesn't wait for Angular?

Tags: protractor

I'm using Protractor v3.2.2 with Node.js v5.10.1 to run tests on Chrome.

Basically what I observed is that one of our tests fails continuously because a form field isn't being filled and the form cannot be submitted. The failing step effectively looks like this:

```
field.sendKeys(value);
checkbox.click();
submitButton.click();
```

If I change it to:

```
field.clear().sendKeys(value);
checkbox.click();
submitButton.click();
```

or:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
field.sendKeys(value);
checkbox.click();
submitButton.click();
```

it passes without a hitch.

So my suspicion is that `sendKeys` doesn't wait for the page to load fully, even though the docs would suggest that all WebDriver actions are invoking `browser.waitForAngular` before execution. Does anyone have any thoughts on the issue? Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an effective results using sendKeys You need to sleep the browser for a specific time.

Add `browser.driver.sleep(500);` before or after your code. This will be effective.

See this.

```
field.sendKeys(value);
browser.driver.sleep(500);

checkbox.click();
browser.driver.sleep(500);

submitButton.click();
```

Comment: Yes, while waiting would help with the issue, it's not a very elegant way of handling such cases (if anything, `browser.wait` would be preferable).My question is not about finding a solution however (since I've mentioned two in the question itself) but rather about whether `sendKeys` behaves as it should (according to docs all WebDriver actions are wrapped with `browser.waitForAngular` by default). I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

try to write in promise so that it will wait.

```
field.sendKeys(value).then(function(){
   checkbox.click().then(function(){
      submitButton.click().then(function(){
        expect(thisToShow).toBe(shown);
     });
   });
});
```